# Comparing values in two SQL Server tables then update based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 database tables and I want to update the first table based on matches between their common columns. Here is my code:

```
update Table1
set comment = 'Valid stuff'
where Name in (
               SELECT T1.name
               FROM Table1 AS T1
               INNER JOIN Table AS T2
                 on T1.name = t2.name
                 and T1.id = T2.id)
```

If there is no match it should add another value like 'bad stuff'. Do you think this is the best thing I should do?

Comment: you only are checking if item in t1 is in t2, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of this:

```
UPDATE T1
SET comment = CASE WHEN ou.name IS NULL THEN 'bad stuff' ELSE 'Valid stuff' END
FROM Table1 T1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT T2.name
             FROM Table T2
             WHERE T1.name = t2.name AND T1.id = T2.id) ou
```

Answer (score -1):

better would be:

```
update t1 set comment = 
  case when exists 
      (Select * from Table 
       Where id = t1.id
          and name = t1.name)
    then 'Valid stuff'
    else 'bad stuff' end
from table1 t1
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be case WHEN and not WHERE?

Comment: @VDK . . . I don't like the conventions used for this answer (`select *` for exists, comparisons between tables with no table aliases).  However, I don't think it merits a downvote, even with a syntax typo -- especially because `case exists` is probably the best answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff unfortunately, it doesn't allow me to remove the downgrade. But got a question for you if you don't mind: Why don't you like SELECT * in the EXISTS?

Comment: @VDK, yes, brain fa*t.   `when` not `where` is correct.

Comment: @VDK,  He doesn't like it - (and please correct me if I misspeak for you Gordon), because in all OTHER uses of `Select *`, (other than in an `Exists` or `Not Exists`), it leaves ambiguous the set of columns to be fetched.  So, in one scenario, for e.g.,  a user who might be depending on a specific column would not be aware, through a compile failure, if that column was misnamed in a future schema change. Other scenarios also are affected. To some SQL users, the fact that none of these consequences are applicable to the use of `select *` in an `exists` does not seem to matter.

Comment: To these folks, perhaps, they are trying to create a simple rule that can be applied by less expert SQL users in all cases without discriminating between cases where it has pitfalls and the few cases where it does not.

Comment: @VDK . . . There is nothing *per se* wrong with it (by contrast, I think `SELECT NULL` is misleading). There is just no reason to suggest that all columns are needed to check for the existence of a row.  Database engines don't actually return all columns, so they short-circuit the processing anyway.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and Charles, thanks for your comments :)